# Never update an excel UDF after creation

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

In excel, I am trying to generate a UUID column in a table using a vba UDF, but I only want it to run the first time it is called so that the UUID that it generates never changes.

Making the UUID is easy (modified from https://nolongerset.com/createguid/ - **edit:** added check for cell A1 to work correctly with answer from @MGonet below):

```vb
'These Declare lines go at the very top of the code module
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32" (id As Any) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32" (id As Any) As Long
#End If


' ----------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure  : CreateGUID
' Author     : Dan (webmaster@1stchoiceav.com)
' Source     : http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/CDB74B0DFA5C75B7C6AFE60D3295A96F.html
' Adapted by : Mike Wolfe
' Republished: https://nolongerset.com/createguid/
' Date       : 8/5/2022
' ----------------------------------------------------------------
Private Function CreateGUID() As String
    'Application.OnRepeat Text:="Paste Next Date", _
                          'Procedure:="Application.thisCell.Text"
     If (Application.thisCell.Address <> "$A$1") Then
            Const S_OK As Long = 0
            Dim id(0 To 15) As Byte
            Dim Cnt As Long, GUID As String
            If CoCreateGuid(id(0)) = S_OK Then
                For Cnt = 0 To 15
                    CreateGUID = CreateGUID & IIf(id(Cnt) < 16, "0", "") + Hex$(id(Cnt))
                Next Cnt
                CreateGUID = LCase(Left$(CreateGUID, 8) & "-" & _
                                   Mid$(CreateGUID, 9, 4) & "-" & _
                                   Mid$(CreateGUID, 13, 4) & "-" & _
                                   Mid$(CreateGUID, 17, 4) & "-" & _
                                   Right$(CreateGUID, 12))
            Else
                MsgBox "Error while creating GUID!"
            End If
        Else
            CreateGUID = Application.thisCell.Text
        End If
End Function
```

What I want is to wrap this in an `If` statement to determine if the function has already been calculated or not. After much mucking around I tried:

```vb
Public Function CreateGUID() As String
     If (Application.thisCell.Characters = "") Then
            'Generate UUID
     Else
            CreateGUID = Application.thisCell.Value
     End If
End Function
```

However this doesn't seem to be working. I also tried mucking around with [application.onrepeat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onrepeat), but that doesn't seem to work either. Is there an alternative approach to determine if a formula has been evaluated yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you want to use this formula in practice.

If you want to keep formula in a cell this enables you to copy cells with formulas, however they will contain the same values, so you need to activate them to get new values. You can achieve this with a UDF:

```vb
Function OneCall()
   If Application.ThisCell.Text = 0 Then
      OneCall = CreateGUID
   Else
       OneCall = Application.ThisCell.Text
   End If
End Function
```

If the sheet is recalculated the cell contents remains unchanged, however if you edit the cell then new value will be generated.

If you prefer a single-use function you can try another approach. In this case the function result is replaced by a constant, so it cannot be changed automatically due to recalculation. But each time you want to generate a new value you must enter new function call to a cell `=EOneCall()`

This is a set of two functions, because our function should be called indirectly.

```vb
Function OneCall2() As String
   With Application.ThisCell
      If .Address <> "$A$1" Then
         .Value = CreateGUID
      End If
   End With
End Function

Function EOneCall() As String
   EOneCall = Evaluate("OneCall2()")
End Function
```

Comment: Wonderful. I wasn't (still am not) really sure how and when excel formula evaluation is triggered, but turning the formula into a string is perfect. However for some reason `EOneCall()` also adds a uuid to cell A1. I managed to modify the `CreateGUID()` function to check if the current cell is A1 and not to evaluate if that is the case (edited into question for future readers), however it seems like a bit of a hack.

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten about this. If you call a UDF function indirectly via the `Evaluate` function, it is in fact called twice: firstly with caller address `A1` and secondly with the proper address. I have made correction to the code.